# Best way to track membership history

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am creating a membership management database. One of the aspects I want to keep track of is the duration of a membership, and I want to keep track of any breaks in membership also.

Example:

A person joins , they renew each year on time for 3 years, but then there is a lapse in renewal for 2 months on the 4th year, and then they renew.  I would like to be able to see the membership period of 3 years, the 2 month lapse, and then the new renewal.

Currently (see image), I originally was planning on just updating the membership_expire field to be a year from the date of the latest renewal but then realized I would be losing the previous membership renewal history by updating that field.... So how do I work around that?

I have a feeling the solution may be to create a seperate table to keep track of each renewal but I am not sure that is the best way to do it.

[image: Database ERD]

Comment: I think that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

The database should reflect the reality.

If a "membership" can have multiple renewals, with different periods,
then your data structure should support it.

meaning- you need to create another table with FK to membership,
and each row would represent a period of time (start and expires)

Comment: So instead of what I have above, I would have:

Member table -> Renewal Table -> Membership Table

Renewal Table would have:
MemberID, MembershipID

Membership Table would have:
MembershipID, start date, expire date

Comment: yes, and you can also add "active_renewal_id" to your Membership table, FK to Renewal table, as there can be only one active.